# What's the syntax to skip optional saga:catchmentareaparallel parameters?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, catchment-area

In PyQGis, I want to use saga:catchmentareaparallel algorithm, in the parameters there is an optional arguments, and I don't want to use them, what is the value should i put on the argument? i try to put null and "" but unfortunately it's not working.

```
processing.runalg('saga:catchmentareaparallel', elevation, sinkroute, weight, material, target, step, method, dolinear, linearthrs, linearthrs_grid, chdir_grid, convergence, carea, cheight, cslope, accu_tot, accu_left, accu_right, caspect, flwpath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the term:

```
None
```

to discount various parameters. Additionally, adding it as an output parameter will create a memory layer for the resulting layer.